# Arbitrary amount of decimals while dividing

Tags: java, decimal

I'm new to programming. I have a task to make a division of two arbitrary numbers, and to set arbitrary number of decimals. I was searching on the internet, but not really sure how to set it. If I could get some help, would much appreciate!

Here's the code so far:

```
    int a,b, decimala;
   System.out.println("first number: ");
   a = unos.nextInt();

   System.out.println("second number: ");
   b = unos.nextInt();

   System.out.println("amount of decimals: ");
   decimala = unos.nextInt();

    double c;

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println("--------------");
    c = (double)a/b;
    System.out.println(%.decimala+ c);
```

Comment: You'd use a `format` function to format the number as a string. Do you want the number to be truncated, or rounded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: A more robust approach is to use the `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output them you could try using `format`

```
String format = "%" + decimala + "f";
System.out.format(format,a);
```

Here's a cheat sheet with all the stuff you can do.

> https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

Thanks to @AndrewGuerra for pointing out how to format a variable amount of decimals

Comment: that wouldn`t work, i have a scanner above to choose the amount of decimals

Comment: In order to form the format string based on the number of decimals specified in your `decimala` variable, you could form the format string by concatenating the variable like so, `"%" + decimala + "f"`, then you can plug this into the format method.

Comment: thanks guys, it helped :D